# How to interpret 'buy' in 'upstart entrepreneurs cannot buy their prizes the prestige of the Nobels'?

Tags: meaning

> What's not to like? Quite a lot, according to a handful of
> scientists... You cannot buy class, as the old saying goes, and these
> upstart entrepreneurs cannot **buy their prizes the prestige** of the
> Nobels. The new awards are an exercise in self-promotion for those
> behind them, say scientists.

It is usual to say 'buy sb sth' or 'buy sth for sb'. But, we have 'buy sth sth' in the sentence above.

In my view, it should be 'entrepreneurs cannot buy their prizes [owning] the prestige of the Nobels.'

Is it right? If not, how to analyze the relationship between 'their prizes' and 'the prestige'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure in that quote is *[ "buy" + indirect object + direct object ]*.

That structure, and *[ "buy" + direct object + "for" + indirect object ]* seem interchangeable, but the first one carries the nuance that it's for the benefit of the indirect object. Compare

> (1) I bought a new seat for my bicycle.
> (2) I bought my bicycle a new seat.

Sentence (1) is normal, without nuance, but (2) implies the seat is for the benefit of my bicycle.

In your context, "*their prizes*" is the indirect object, and "*the prestige of the Nobels*" is the direct object. Using structure (2) makes sense here because it would greatly benefit those awards to have the prestige of the Nobel Prizes.

Answer (score 2):

At first it did not seem grammatical to me (because I was unfamiliar with the context, not because the syntax is unusual); it is parsed so:

> ... they cannot buy their child a prancing pony.

They cannot purchase for their prizes the prestige of the Nobels.

> They cannot buy their 1990s-era condo a place on the National  Register of Historic Places.

Answer (score -2):

### Meaning In Context

This phrase is saying "even if someone spends a lot of money, they cannot instantly win prestige or high status."

Breaking the phrase into parts and context:

- **Upstart entrepreneurs** - people who are new to entrepreneurship/owning a business and who are overly confident or presumptuous. There is added context here because the article is talking about business owners who are starting scientific research companies. The scientific community (at least in the US, but I believe internationally) is often skeptical of business fields.
- **their prizes** - this is implying that the entrepreneurs are creating or inventing their own awards, rather than competing for ones that already exist.
- **prestige of the Nobels** - The Nobel prizes are the most prestigious award given in many fields. An award with the prestige of the Nobels would be world-renown and remarkable.

### Grammar

The order here looks like it breaks rules or is odd, but it is fairly common in spoken and written English. It's not uncommon to see "buy [recipient] [object]" or "give [recipient] [object]". You could change this word order to be "buy [object] for [recipient]".

So in this case, you can think of this as "buy the prestige of the Nobels for their prizes" the meaning is the same. The sentence suggests purchasing prestige that would then belong to the prizes.

It's written in a flipped order to make it emphasize the prizes (the recipient). This flip gives readers the context of the prizes before saying what is being purchased for them.

Comment: No - "their prizes" refers to the scientists (who have been "won" in the corporate scramble to buy up talent). But although the "upstart entrepreneurs" (Google? Microsoft? Apple?) can pay top salaries, they can't attract top scientists with Nobel prizes.